# Is there a public Plastic SCM test server I can connect to?

Tags: plasticscm

Is there a public [Plastic SCM](https://www.plasticscm.com/) test server I can connect to make sure my client is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the evaluation guide here: http://www.plasticscm.com/evaluation-guide/index.html

That being said, there are several ways to check everything is ready:

- Go to the command line
- Type

  `cm lrep YOURSERVER:PORT`

  sample: `cm lrep localhost:8087`
- If returns the repositories, then everything is working

Alternatively you can run the:

```
cm cc
```

command which stands for "check connection" against the server configured by default.

I personally prefer `cm lrep` though.